# SQLite access using Powershell and PSSqlite - SELECT query fails

Tags: windows, powershell, sqlite

I am trying to write a Powershell script to write data to a SQLite database and to read from it. I'm using the [PSSQLite](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite) module to do this.  The script works on one server, but not on the other. Both machines are Windows 2012 R2.

Both machines look like this:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\> Import-Module PSSQLite
PS C:\> Get-Module PSSQLite

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.3      PSSQLite                            {Invoke-SQLiteBulkCopy, Invoke-SqliteQuery, New-SQLiteConn...

PS C:\>
```

I have a short Powershell script to create a SQLite database, create a table within it, write to the table, and then read from the table. The script looks like this:

```
Import-Module PSSQLite
$secretsDatabase = ".\secrets.db"

if (Test-Path $secretsDatabase) {
    Write-Host "$secretsDatabase  already exists"
} else {
   $create_query = "create table secrets (tid string, password string, username string)"
   $cq_result  = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $create_query 

   $add_secrets_query = "insert into secrets (tid, password, username) values ('xx1', 'somepassword', 'bob@example.com')"
   $as_result = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $add_secrets_query
}

$secretsQuery = "select tid, password, username from secrets limit 1"

$result = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $secretsQuery
Write-Host $result
```

When I run this Powershell script on one server, the output looks like this:

```
PS C:\> C:\sqlite_test.ps1
.\secrets.db  already exists
@{tid=xx1; password=somepassword; username=bob@example.com}

PS C:\>
```

This is the expected output.

When I run the same script on the other server, the output looks like this:

```
PS C:\> C:\sqlite_test.ps1
.\secrets.db  already exists
Unable to find type [DBNullScrubber].
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSSQLite\1.0.3\Invoke-SqliteQuery.ps1:518 char:25
+                         [DBNullScrubber]::DataRowToPSObject($row)
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DBNullScrubber:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound


PS C:\>
```

On both systems, the SQL queries to create a table and to insert a row works. This is evidenced by using the command line utility on both machines and getting this result:

```
C:\> sqlite3 secrets.db
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE secrets (tid string, password string, username string);
INSERT INTO secrets VALUES('xx1','somepassword','bob@example.com');
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

However the SELECT query on one machine fails because of the "[DBNullScrubber]" error.  How can I correct this problem on the one machine?

------ UPDATE: August 13, 2017  more analysis -----------------

I did some code spelunking at the GitHub repo for this module, into the file

[Invoke-SqliteQuery.ps1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite/master/PSSQLite/Invoke-SqliteQuery.ps1)

I went into my Powershell on the bad server and ran this code snippet from that file:

```
$cSharp = @'
                using System;
                using System.Data;
                using System.Management.Automation;

                public class DBNullScrubber
                {
                    public static PSObject DataRowToPSObject(DataRow row)
                    {
                        PSObject psObject = new PSObject();

                        if (row != null && (row.RowState & DataRowState.Detached) != DataRowState.Detached)
                        {
                            foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
                            {
                                Object value = null;
                                if (!row.IsNull(column))
                                {
                                    value = row[column];
                                }

                                psObject.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty(column.ColumnName, value));
                            }
                        }

                        return psObject;
                    }
                }
'@
```

This snippet defines the DBNullScrubber class. After that, I went to my command line on the bad server and ran:

```
PS C:\>  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Data','System.Xml'
Add-Type : (0) : Warning as Error: Invalid search path 'D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find 
the path specified. '
(1) :                 using System;
At line:1 char:2
+  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Data' ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (error CS1668: W...th specified. ':CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
At line:1 char:2
+  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Data' ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand


PS C:>
```

I ran this on the good server and there were no errors.

At this point I don't know what to do. How can I fix this?

-----------------  Update Aug 13, 2017 - 12:11 ----------------

I printed out $env:Lib. There was nothing defined on the good machine. On the bad machine it said:

```
PS C:\> $env:Lib
;D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB
PS C:\>
```

Comment: Show `$env:LIB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following to delete the Lib environment variable.

```
Remove-Item $env:Lib
```

Better yet, save the old value, run the script, and then restore the old value.

```
Import-Module PSSQLite
$secretsDatabase = ".\secrets.db"

$envlib = $env:Lib
Remove-Item env:Lib

if (Test-Path $secretsDatabase) {
    Write-Host "$secretsDatabase  already exists"
} else {
   $create_query = "create table secrets (tid string, password string, username string)"
   $cq_result  = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $create_query 

   $add_secrets_query = "insert into secrets (tid, password, username) values ('xx1', 'somepassword', 'bob@example.com')"
   $as_result = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $add_secrets_query
}

$secretsQuery = "select tid, password, username from secrets limit 1"

$result = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $secretsDatabase -Query $secretsQuery
Write-Host $result

$env:Lib = $envlib
```