# Can I access winsqlite3.dll with PowerShell on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, sqlite, windows-10

Since Windows 10 comes with `winsqlite3.dll` preinstalled, I am wondering if Microsoft also supplies cmdlets so that I can use sqlite3 in PowerShell.

If not, what would be the most standard way to use sqlite3 in PowerShell?

Comment: [SQLite access using Powershell and PSSqlite - SELECT query fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45656894/205233) mentions [PSSQLite](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite) but the project doesn't seem to be too active.

Comment: I needed a database on a Windows installation where I  was not allowed to install anything. So I wrote my own wrapper that you might be [interested in](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/winsqlite3_dll/PowerShell/index)

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger it is complicated script (at least for me). It looks nice and tidy, but still too complicated for me. :) I need only to read several values from several tables. Is there document how the strings and numbers are encoded in the file? Sorry, but did not find understandable for me. So I want to find string in SQLite3 database file, read ahead and process to find another string, find next table and find the second string and read around and process.

Comment: This SQLite .NET interop open source wrapper https://github.com/smourier/SQLNado supports winsqlite3.dll automatically when it finds it, and you can use C# with PowerShell so it should pretty easy to combine both.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:
[SQLite querying using embedded C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488519/sqlite-querying-using-embedded-c-sharp/76488520#76488520)

I made a solution for Powershell via an embedded C# code, which does not need any external module.