# SQLite querying using embedded C#

Tags: powershell, sqlite

How can I query an SQLite database using embedded C# code within PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76488520/45375), which is a lightweight way of using SQLite from PowerShell without needing to install modules or libraries.
Additionally, it also works on ARM64 machines, whereas NuGet packages such as [`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) and [`System.Data.SQLite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) currently don't.

I've taken the liberty of adapting your code in the following ways:

- Made the code cross-edition (runs both in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7+) and cross-platform; note: tested on Windows and macOS - not sure about Linux.
- Made the API more PowerShell-friendly (returning *data* rather than passing through result codes and requiring by-ref parameters; use of exceptions)
- Unicode support (SQLite uses UTF-8 internally, which `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` misinterprets).
- Improved data-type support:

  - The `DataTable` instance that is returned for query results now uses `object` columns so as to support all .NET types that correspond to the  SQLite data types (if you use just `$dataTableInstance.Columns.Add(<string>)`, you'll get *string* columns).
  - The `INTEGER` SQLite type is mapped onto `System.Int64` (`[long]`) to ensure that no overflow occurs.

---

**Definition of static helper class `[SqliteHelper]`** via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Type) and ad hoc-compiled C# code that makes P/Invoke calls to the native SQLite library; incurs a one-time compilation performance penalty per session:

```bash
# Compile helper type [SqliteHelper], which is a thin layer on top of the C/C++
# SQLite API.
# Gratefully adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76488520/45375
# Determine the platform-appropriate name of the native SQLite library.
# Note: Tested on Windows and macOS.
$libName = ('sqlite3', 'winsqlite3.dll')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
# Compile the code.
# NOTE:
#   * Re -ReferencedAssemblies:
#      * System.Data.Common, System.Collections are needed for PS Core, System.Xml is needed for WinPS.
#   * For the sake of WinPS compatibility:
#     * The code below uses (a) legacy properyt-definition syntax and (b) legacy dictionary initializer syntax.
#     * The *16() variants of the SQLite functions are used so that .NET (UTF-16LE) strings can be used / converted via
#       Marshal.PtrToStringUni().
#       Behind the scenes, SQLite still translates to and from UTF-8, but not having to deal with that on the .NET
#       side makes things easier, given that only .NET (Core) suports Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8() 
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Collections, System.Data, System.Data.Common, System.Xml -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class SqliteHelper {
  [DllImport("$libName", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint="sqlite3_open16")]            private static extern int    open(string filename, out IntPtr db);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_extended_result_codes")]                      private static extern int    result_codes(IntPtr db, int onOrOff);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_close_v2")]                                   private static extern int    close(IntPtr db);
  [DllImport("$libName", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint="sqlite3_prepare16")]         private static extern int    prepare(IntPtr db, string query, int len, out IntPtr stmt, IntPtr dummy);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_step")]                                       private static extern int    step(IntPtr stmt);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_count")]                               private static extern int    column_count( IntPtr stmt);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_name16")]                              private static extern IntPtr column_name(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_type")]                                private static extern int    column_type(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_double")]                              private static extern Double column_double(IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_int")]                                 private static extern int    column_int(   IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_int64")]                               private static extern Int64  column_int64( IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_text16")]                              private static extern IntPtr column_text(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_blob")]                                private static extern IntPtr column_blob(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_bytes")]                               private static extern int    column_bytes( IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_finalize")]                                   private static extern int    finalize(IntPtr stmt);

  // Important result codes.
  private const int SQLITE_OK = 0; 
  private const int SQLITE_ROW = 100; // step() indicates that at least 1 more row exists.
  private const int SQLITE_DONE = 101; // step() indicates that therea are no (more) rows.
  // Data type IDs
  private const int SQLITE_INTEGER = 1;
  private const int SQLITE_FLOAT = 2;
  private const int SQLITE_TEXT = 3;
  private const int SQLITE_BLOB = 4;
  private const int SQLITE_NULL = 5;

  // A helper exception to report SQLite result codes that are errors.
  public class SqliteException : Exception {
    private int _nativeErrorCode; 
    public int NativeErrorCode { get { return _nativeErrorCode; } set { _nativeErrorCode = value; } }
    public SqliteException(int code) : this(String.Format("SQLite API call failed with result code {0}.", code), code) {}
    public SqliteException(string message, int code) : base(message) { NativeErrorCode = code; }
  }

  public static IntPtr Open(string filename) {
      IntPtr db;
      int result = open(filename, out db);
      if (result != SQLITE_OK) throw new SqliteException(result);
      result = result_codes(db, 1); // report extended result codes by default.
      if (result != SQLITE_OK) throw new SqliteException(result);
      return db;
  }

  public static void Close(IntPtr db) {
      int result = close(db);
      if (result != SQLITE_OK) throw new SqliteException(result);
  }

  public static DataTable Execute(IntPtr db, string query) {
      IntPtr stmt;
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      int result = prepare(db, query, -1, out stmt, IntPtr.Zero);
      if (result != SQLITE_OK) throw new SqliteException(result);

      int colCount = column_count(stmt);

      // Get the first row so that column namescan be determined.
      result = step(stmt);
      if (result == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Add corresponding columns to the data-table object.
        // NOTE: Since any column value can be NULL, we cannot infer fixed data
        //       types for the columns and therefore *must* use typeof(object).
        for (int c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
          dt.Columns.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(column_name(stmt, c)), typeof(object));
        }
      } else if (result == SQLITE_DONE) { // Either a query without results or a non-query statement.
        result = finalize(stmt);
        if (result != 0) throw new SqliteException(result);
        // For simplicity, return an empty DataTable instance either way.
        // In a PowerShell pipeline, its .Rows collection is automatically enumerated,
        // meaning that *no* objects are sent through the pipeline.
        // If a non-query's output isn't captured (which shouldn't be necessary), PowerShell's automatic enumeration
        // in the pipeline ensures that *no* output stream pollution occurs.
        return dt;
      } else {
        throw new SqliteException(result);
      }

      // Fetch all rows and populate a DataTable instance with them.
      object[] rowData = new object[colCount];
      do {
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
          // Note: The column types must be determined for each and every row,
          //       given that NULL values may be present.
          switch (column_type(stmt, i)) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER: // covers all integer types up to System.Int64
              rowData[i] = column_int64(stmt, i);
              break;
            case SQLITE_FLOAT:
              rowData[i] = column_double(stmt, i);
              break;
            case SQLITE_TEXT:
              rowData[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(column_text(stmt, i));
              break;
            case SQLITE_BLOB:
              IntPtr ptr = column_blob(stmt, i);
              int len = column_bytes(stmt, i);
              byte[] arr = new byte[len];
              Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
              rowData[i] = arr;
              break;
            case SQLITE_NULL: 
              rowData[i] = DBNull.Value;
              break;
            default:
              throw new Exception(String.Format("DESIGN ERROR: Unexpected column-type ID: {0}", column_type(stmt, i)));
          }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
      } while (step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW);

      result = finalize(stmt);
      if (result != SQLITE_OK) throw new SqliteException(result);

      return dt;
  }
}
"@
```

**Sample usage** (assumes that you've run the `Add-Type` command above beforehand):

```bash
# Abort on (uncaught) errors.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Open an in-memory database (':memory:')
# To open - or create on demand - a database *file*,
# pass its *full path* of the database file.
# To convert a *relative* path to a full one:
#  * If the file exists, use (Convert-Path $relativePath)
#  * Otherwise, use "$PWD/$relativePath"
$db = [SqliteHelper]::Open(':memory:')

# NOTE:
# Submit ONE statement at a time with ::Execute() (";" terminator is optional).

# Create a sample table.
# NOTE: This fails, if the table already exists.
# Non-ASCII characters are included to test if character-encoding issues arise.
[SqliteHelper]::Execute($db, @'
  create table sample_table (Name string, Äge int)
'@)

# Insert rows into the sample table.
# Non-ASCII characters are included to test if character-encoding issues arise.
# A 64-bit integer is included to test if overflow issues arise.
[SqliteHelper]::Execute($db, @'
  insert into sample_table (Name, Äge) values ('JDoë', 42), ('JRoe', 5856288576210)
'@)
 
# Submit a sample query.
$query = @'
SELECT * FROM sample_table;
'@
$dataTable = [SqliteHelper]::Execute($db, $query)

# Display the results.
$dataTable

# Close the database.
[SqliteHelper]::Close($db)
```

Comment: Nice work! Have you tested the Ansi/Unicode change? In my environment the official encoding was showing weired characters in columns with special charcaters like "ÄÖÜ".

Comment: Tested your code in multiple scenarios. All good - excellent job!

Comment: If I have any value as DBNULL, then this does not work anymore. Just create an extra column to your sample which you dont fill and you will see. Any idea why?

Comment: I think its realted to your embededd code where the dictionary has no mapping for SQLITE_NULL as a key.

Comment: Good catch, @Carsten. Please see my update, which should fix the problem. I had to make all data-table columns `typeof(object)`, and the column data types are now queried for each and every row, given that any column value can be `NULL` - this is somewhat unfortunate performance-wise, but actually simplifies the code (the dictionary for mapping SQL types to .NET types is no longer needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by leveraging the System.Data namespace in PowerShell and embedding C# code that interacts with the SQLite database. Here's an approach using the winsqlite3.dll library for SQLite functionality:

```
cls
Remove-Variable * -ea 0
$errorActionPreference = 'stop'

$libName = ('sqlite3', 'winsqlite3.dll')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT']
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Data, System.Xml -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Sqlite {
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_open16", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]    public  static extern int    open(string filename, out IntPtr db);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_prepare16", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] private static extern int    prepare(IntPtr db, string query, int len, out IntPtr stmt, IntPtr dummy);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_step")]                               private static extern int    step(IntPtr stmt);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_count")]                       private static extern int    column_count( IntPtr stmt);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_name16")]                      private static extern IntPtr column_name(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_type")]                        private static extern int    column_type(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_double")]                      private static extern Double column_double(IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_int")]                         private static extern int    column_int(   IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_int64")]                       private static extern Int64  column_int64( IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_text16")]                      private static extern IntPtr column_text(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_blob")]                        private static extern IntPtr column_blob(  IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_column_bytes")]                       private static extern int    column_bytes( IntPtr stmt, int col);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_finalize")]                           private static extern int    finalize(IntPtr stmt);
  [DllImport("$libName", EntryPoint="sqlite3_close_v2")]                           public  static extern int    close(IntPtr db);

   public static DataTable Execute(IntPtr db, string query) {
      IntPtr stmt = IntPtr.Zero;
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      int result = prepare(db, query, -1, out stmt, IntPtr.Zero);
      if (stmt == IntPtr.Zero) {return dt;}
      int colCount = column_count(stmt);
      int[] columnTypes = new int[colCount];

      if (step(stmt) == 100) {
        for (int c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
          columnTypes[c] = column_type(stmt, c);
          dt.Columns.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(column_name(stmt, c)), typeof(object));
        }
      } else {
        result = finalize(stmt);
        return dt;
      }

      object[] rowData = new object[colCount];
      do {
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
          switch (columnTypes[i]) {
            case 1:
              rowData[i] = column_int64(stmt, i);
              break;
            case 2:
              rowData[i] = column_double(stmt, i);
              break;
            case 3:
              rowData[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(column_text(stmt, i));
              break;
            case 4:
              IntPtr ptr = column_blob(stmt, i);
              int len = column_bytes(stmt, i);
              byte[] arr = new byte[len];
              Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
              rowData[i] = arr;
              break;
            default: 
              rowData[i] = DBNull.Value;
              break;
          }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
      } while (step(stmt) == 100);

      result = finalize(stmt);
      return dt;
  }
}
"@

# Sample query
$query = @"
SELECT * FROM MyTable
"@

# Connect to the database file or use ':memory:' for in-memory DB
$db = [IntPtr]::Zero
$filename = "path/to/your/database.sqlite3"
$result = [sqlite]::open($filename, [ref]$db)

if ($result -eq 0) {
    # Query the database
    $dataTable = [sqlite]::dbquery($db, $query)

    # Display the result
    $dataTable
}
else {
    Write-Host "Database connection failed."
}

# Close the database connection
[sqlite]::close($db)
```

Here's a breakdown of what the code does:

The embedded C# code defines a static class sqlite with DLL imports for the SQLite functions you'll need. It also includes a dbquery method for executing SQL queries and retrieving the results as a DataTable.

The PowerShell script connects to the SQLite database by calling [sqlite]::open with the database filename. If the connection is successful, it retrieves an IntPtr representing the database connection (db).

The script executes the sample query by calling [sqlite]::dbquery and passing the database connection (db) and the query string. The results are stored in a DataTable object.

The script displays the resulting DataTable object, which contains the retrieved data from the database. You can modify this part as needed to format or further process the data.

Finally, the script closes the database connection using [sqlite]::close.

Comment: Does someone know how to add sqlite3_open_v2 to it to read a file in read-only mode?
Whenever I test it, it throws an error 1.

Comment: I see that you've now accepted your own answer - which is obviously fine if it best solves your problem, but I'm curious: did you find a problem in my answer and/or in what way does your answer improve on it?

Comment: It uses the columnTypes as an array instead of getting the type again and again.
If you insert that part into your code I can switch back. Maybe you can add the open_v2 function to open a DB in read-only mode?

Comment: Thanks, @Carsten - I haven't looked at open_v2. As for the column types: The whole point of the latest update to my answer was to account for the fact that in SQLite columns only have type _affinity_; that is,  individual values in a given row can still be of _any type_, including `NULL` - hence the need to dynamically determine column types for each and every row.