# Powershell SQLite query gets an int64 wrong

Tags: powershell, sqlite, integer, long-integer

I have a database built with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE starsystems
(
   name TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
   systemaddress INT UNIQUE,
   CONSTRAINT combined_uniques UNIQUE (name, systemaddress)
)
```

(and i can't change how the DB and the table is made)

One of the fields contains these data:

```
Name: "61 Cygni", systemaddress: 5856288576210
```

I'm using powershell to execute this query to fill a dataset:

```
$oSQLiteDBCommand.Commandtext='SELECT name, systemaddress FROM starsystems WHERE name IS "61 Cygni" '
```

But my result is:

```
61 Cygni, -2046815534
```

So, for some reason, the systemaddress field i get is like

```
(systemaddress & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) | 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
```

(sorry for the horrible explanation, i lack the right english words, please pardon me).

What am i doing wrong and what should i do instead?
And, since i need to change the systemaddress value, what should i do it to avoid this kind of unwanted conversion?

Comment: The implication is that `INT` is a 64-bit integer in SQLite, but it gets truncated to a 32-bit integer in the query result on the PowerShell side.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i've found is to cast the INT field to text:

```
SELECT name, cast(systemaddress as text) as sysadd FROM starsystems WHERE name IS "61 Cygni"
```

The alias `sysadd` is handy 'cause it gives an easier column name than `cast(systemaddress as text)`.

Comment: Good to know a workaround, but it would be good to know if there's a proper solution. What are you using on the PowerShell side to communicate with SQLite?

Comment: @mklement0: this is the code i use to query the DB: https://pastebin.com/851vQnsq

Comment: Thanks; I see that you're using the [`System.Data.SQLite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)  NuGet package. A homegrown alternative that maps `INTEGER` SQLite values to `System.Int64` .NET values can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76515318/45375).

Comment: Thanks to you. I've "just" copy-pasted code from tutorials and from answers here and adjusted it until it worked, so i don't really understand what a NuGet package is... but if the answer you linked resolves it better, i'll try that and see if i can get it to works: i should have already learned something in the process :D

Comment: A NuGet packages are a pre-built .NET libraries (assemblies), typically downloaded from https://www.nuget.org/ While they're well supported in .NET SDK projects, their use from PowerShell is difficult - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537273/45375). The previously linked answer is dependency-free; it uses `Add-Type` to compile C# code on demand that directly interacts with the native SQLite library.